# folding in scala clarification

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fold

Want to improve piece of code by folding operation

this code works

```
var r = 0
arr.foreach { s =>
  val count = arr.count(_ == s)
  if (count > r) r = count
}
```

But in case with fold. I have an error with types.

```
Error:(44, 49) type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, String) => Any
 required: (Any, Any) => Any
      arr.fold(0: Int)((result: Int, s: String) => {
                                                ^

  arr.fold(0: Int)((result: Int, s: String) => {
    val count = arr.count(_ == s)
    if (count > result) count
  })
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to find the string with most occurrences in the the array, you can use `groupBy`:

```
val arr = Array("yuval", "yuval", "david")
arr.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length).max._2

arr: Array[String] = Array(yuval, yuval, david)
res1: Int = 2
```

If you really want to jump to hoops of using fold, you'll either need `foldLeft` or `foldRight` which pass the accumulator along for each value in the sequence:

```
val arr = Array("yuval", "yuval", "david")
val aggregatedMap = arr.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int].withDefaultValue(0)) {
  case (map, value) => map.updated(value, map(value) + 1)
}

println(aggregatedMap.max._2)
```